# Power BI Waterfall Chart Issue with Excluding Item from Breakdown

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm facing an issue with my Waterfall chart in Power BI, specifically when trying to exclude the item "A" from the breakdown. I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Here's a brief overview of the issue:

1. Start point: I want to display the Prior Period  value for the item "A" in the Waterfall chart.
2. End point: I also want to display the Current Period  value for the item "B" as the end point in the Waterfall chart.
3. Between: For the items other than "A", I want to display the Variance  value in the Waterfall chart.

| LEVEL2 | Prior | Current | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | X | X |
| B | X | X | X |
| C | X | X | X |
| D | X | X | X |
| Total | X | X | X |

I've tried using various DAX expressions, including the SWITCH function and conditional statements, but I haven't been successful in achieving the desired outcome. When I try to exclude the "A" item from the breakdown, the chart ends up being empty.

Here's the DAX expression I'm currently using:

> walk =  VAR walkitem = SELECTEDVALUE(Walk[Value]) RETURN
> SWITCH(
> walkitem,
> "CY", CALCULATE([Current], [LEVEL2] = "A"),
> "PY", IF(COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES([LEVEL2]), [LEVEL2] <> "A")) = 1, -[Variance], CALCULATE([Prior], [LEVEL2] = "A")),
> BLANK()
> )

But unfortunately I still see A as breakdown, for example

[image: example]